# aspnet core unable to resolve dependency: error:'Unable to resolve service for type while attempting to activate'

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

I am getting a dependancy injection error when i try to access my controller. the error is 'unable to resolve service for IOrderPartRepository while attempting to activate. I followed examples from tutorials, but am still not sure why it won't resolve. I reviewed similar questions, but it looked like i had incorporated the fix from similar questions in my solution

Error:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
      Route matched with {action = "GetOrderParts", controller = "OrderPart"}. Executing controller action with signature System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult] GetOrderParts(DatingApp.API.Helpers.UserParams) on controller DatingApp.API.Controllers.UsersController (DatingApp.API).
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action DatingApp.API.Controllers.UsersController.GetOrderParts (DatingApp.API) in 3.2277ms
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'DatingApp.API.Data.IOrderPartRepository' while attempting to activate 'DatingApp.API.Controllers.OrderPartController'.

Here is the code

```
public interface IOrderPartRepository
{
     void Add<T>(T entity) where T: class;
     void Delete<T>(T entity) where T: class;
     Task<bool> SaveAll();
     Task<PagedList<OrderPart>> GetOrderParts(UserParams userParams);
     Task<OrderPart> GetOrderPart(int id);
}

public class OrderPartRepository: IOrderPartRepository
{
    private readonly DataContext _context;


    public OrderPartRepository(DataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public void Add<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        _context.Add(entity);
    }

    public void Delete<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        _context.Remove(entity);
    }

    public async Task<OrderPart> GetOrderPart(int id)
    {
        var orderPart = await _context.OrderParts.Include(p => p.Photos).FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == id);

        return orderPart;
    }

    public async Task<PagedList<OrderPart>> GetOrderParts(UserParams userParams)
    {
        var orderparts = _context.OrderParts.Include(p => p.Photos)
            .OrderByDescending(u => u.Added).AsQueryable();


        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userParams.OrderBy))
        {
            switch (userParams.OrderBy)
            {
                case "created":
                    orderparts = orderparts.OrderByDescending(u => u.Added);
                    break;
                default:
                    orderparts = orderparts.OrderByDescending(u => u.Added);
                    break;
            }
        }

        return await PagedList<OrderPart>.CreateAsync(orderparts, userParams.PageNumber, userParams.PageSize);
    }

    public async Task<bool> SaveAll()
    {
        return await _context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;
    }

}
}
```

**controller**

```
private readonly IOrderPartRepository _repo;

public OrderPartController(IOrderPartRepository repo)
{
   this._repo = repo;
}
```

**startup**

```
services.AddScoped<IAuthRepository, AuthRepository>();
services.AddScoped<IDatingRepository, DatingRepository>();
services.AddScoped<IOrderPartRepository, OrderPartRepository>();
```

Comment: I took the majority of your code, substituting `DataContext` with one in a project I already had, and left out code where you have other classes which you didn't include and it seemed to work fine. So, have you registered your `DataContext` in `Startup.cs`? Also, do any of your other classes such as `PagedList` have any constructors that take services that would need registering?

Comment: @Stuart - Yes I registered my data context in startup.cs. All services have been registered in startup.

Answer (score 4):

Did you register your DB context in the `Startup` class too? If not, that might be the reason of the problem, try something like:

```
services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => {
    options.UseSqlServer("Connection string");
});
```

Comment: Yes, I did 
 services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(x => x.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

Comment: You need to post more code then, everything looks ok in your question.

Comment: My error. I had methods for configureservices and configuredevelopmentservices and i hadn't registered the dependency in the configuredevelopmentservices method